# Need help for specific date format

Tags: iphone, ios, date, date-format

I have next date string,

```
2011-08-30T11:44:54.345-04:00
```

Help me to compose right format to parse it with `dateFromString:`

Answer (score 1):

You need to eliminate the last colon (timezone, "-04:00" -> "-0400"), as `Z` will take something like "-0800", then you can give this a try:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2011-08-30T11:44:54.345-04:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddEHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormat release];
```

For more information on date formatting, refer to [this page](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 0):

This is following the tilo's answer but with few things added.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2011-08-30T11:44:54.345-04:00";
NSRange range = [dateString rangeOfString:@":" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"" options:0 range:range];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddEHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormat release];
```

You would get the required format.