# Trying to format a Date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

in xcode 'm using touchXML and im calling a webservice. in my xml file i have a line like this

```
<a:DateIn>2011-10-28T08:12:58.36+02:00</a:DateIn>
```

im calling it and it appears in my simulator like like this 2011-10-28T08:12:58.36+02:00

my code in xcode loos like this

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
        dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
           reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[blogEntries
            objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"a:DateIn"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"a:Description"];
cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0];

return cell;
}
```

i want to convert the date to month:day hours:minutes

Comment: See my post at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873690/need-help-for-specific-date-format/7874076#7874076).

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try that whether that works.

Comment: im showing the actual time, but i want to show the time from DateIn ?

Comment: It's a simple date formatter problem, other than the "catch" that NSDateFormatter can't handle the ":" in the timezone offset, so the input string needs to be massaged to remove that first.

Comment: Can any one help with that question, do i need a workaround or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
            dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
               reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
      cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[blogEntries
                objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"a:DateIn"];
    //NSString *dateString = @"2011-10-28T08:12:58.36+02:00";
    NSString *dateString = [item objectForKey:@"a:DateIn"];
    //To convert the string to NSDate

    NSRange range = [dateString rangeOfString:@":" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"" options:0 range:range];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddEHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFormat release];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"MM:dd HH:mm"];
    NSString *dateString1 = [dateFormat1 stringFromDate:date];
    [dateFormat1 release];

    //dateString1 is the required string.
    cell.textLabel.text = dateString1;


    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"a:Description"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i dont understand where i should put this in the code and i cant see how it should work...

Comment: I have updated my answer so that you can easily understand my answer.

Comment: it worked thank you very mucj, but i get the hours wrong, i should get 08:15, but i get 00:15 ?

Comment: Yes, NSDate always gives GMT time. For example, just try `NSLog(@"%@",[NSDate date]);`. So, here you will get (Given time + Your device zone - Time zone given in the string format) as the output.

Comment: Then how can i get the actual time ?

Comment: im showing the actual time, but i want to show the time from DateIn ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *dateform;

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

dateform = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object objectForKey:@"a:DateIn"]];
NSLog(@"before dateform %@",dateform);
dateform = [self dateFormater:dateform];
NSLog(@"afters dateform %@",dateform);
}


-(NSString *)dateFormater:(NSDate *)oldDate
{
        //NSDate *date1 = [[invoice objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"date"];
        NSString *dateStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",oldDate];
        NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dtF setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000"];
        NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:dateStr];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatStr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatStr setDateFormat:@"d-MMM-yyyy"];
        NSString *strDate = [dateFormatStr stringFromDate:d]; 
        [dtF release];
        [dateFormatStr release];
        return strDate;
    }
```

Comment: Where should i put the a:DateIn ?

Comment: dateform = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object objectForKey:@"a:DateIn"]];
dateform = [self dateFormater:dateform];

Comment: i cant get this to work, can you write the code more specific or can you write the whole code again including the dateform ?

Comment: before i build i put a breakpoint to see if the builder runs through the -(NSString *)dateFormater:(NSDate *)oldDate but it dosent, so the code dosent run it throuhg ?